# Normal map does not bake according to UV

Tags: normal-map

I am following Grant Abbit's rock tutorials on baking, and I cannot understand what my mistake is: The normal map won't bake to the Unwrapped texture of the low poly.

I have unwrapped the low poly rock, assigned the according map and selected it. Then I select the h-poly and shift-select the low-poly, etc. Here is a screenshot:

[image]

[image]

Why is not the model baked to the UV map? Thank you.
MODEL:https://www.mediafire.com/file/a19za1ycal50yqc/13+3.blend/file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably doing it wrong. In the screenshot you show, the active object (the last selected if you select it in the 3D view) is the high-poly as we can see on the top left of the 3D view or in the *Outliner*, it should be the other way around, it should be the low-poly that is active, otherwise you bake the low-poly onto the high-poly, so make sure that the active object is the low-poly: In the 3D view select the high-poly then <kbd>Shift</kbd> select the low-poly, or in the *Outliner* select the high-poly then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> select the low-poly, or in the *Outliner* select the low-poly and <kbd>Shift</kbd> select the high-poly (yes a bit confusing as <kbd>Shift</kbd> doesn't work the same way in the 3D view and in the *Outliner*).

Comment: You are definitely right. The problem is: I chose my objects from the list in the Out-liner, h-poly first, L-poly second, and it keeps the FIRST selection (the high poly) as active! However, if I choose them from the 3d view-port everything's fine.  Is this normal?

Comment: I've edited, in th Outliner select the HP then Ctrl select the LP, don't use Shift, a bit confusing as it doesn't work as in the 3D view

Comment: That's it! Thank you!